# File name wildcard

Tags: command

I understand . means current directory, and * means any string. My question is the following 2 commands have the same result? I would appeciate your help.

```
chown -R joe:staff . 
chown -R joe:staff *
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` expands to all filenames in the current directory, excluding hidden files (whose names start with `.`).

So

```
chown -R joe:staff *
```

changes the ownership of all non-hidden files and directories in the current directory, and all the contents of all the non-hidden directories in the current directory.

```
chown -R joe:staff .
```

changes the ownership of the current directory and all its contents, including hidden files and directories.

They don't have the same result: the first doesn't change the current directory or hidden files in the current directory.

Comment: So, (1) ``chown -R joe:staff .`` changes more, and (2) neither changes anything above it. Is that right?

Comment: That's exactly it.